# Find the total number of items listed on facebook marketplace

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketplace

Is there anyway I can find the total number of ads/listings on Facebook Marketplace for a specific country?

E.g.: I want to find the total number of cars listed on Facebook Marketplace in NZ.

1. Does Facebook have any statistics which would provide this info?
2. Is it possible to limit the search result to a specific country? I can only filter by cities?

[image]

Comment: Also looking, let me know if you found something :).

Comment: @StefanRogin: Couldn't find a way.

Comment: Thx Hooman! For the stats I ended up just making a guesstimate by limiting the results and scrolling and counting until no more results are found. 
Ofc this is not really possible with large datasets. A pity they don't open it up. :|